# Output / render template in multiple places, separate from ngIf condition

Tags: angular, angular-template

Say in an Angular template I want to choose the location to render an embedded view (`<ng-template>`) based on some condition.

```html
<ng-template #foo>
  Hello World.
</ng-template>

<p *ngIf="isBar; else baz">
  Bar:  <!-- Want to insert #foo here, sometimes -->
</p>
<div #baz>
  Baz:  <!-- Want to insert #foo over here instead, other times -->
</div>
```

I've used the `else` part of an `*ngIf` to insert a template defined elsewhere. I could write `*ngIf="false; else #foo"` to render the embedded view template, but I feel that shouldn't be necessary.

```html
<p *ngIf="isBar; else baz">
  Bar:  <ng-container *ngIf="false; else foo"></ng-container>
</p>
<div #baz>
  Baz:  <ng-container *ngIf="false; else foo"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `NgTemplateOutput` which "Inserts an embedded view from a prepared `TemplateRef`."

https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

```html
<ng-template #foo>
  Hello World.
</ng-template>

<p *ngIf="isBar; else baz">
  Bar:  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="foo"></ng-container>
</p>
<div #baz>
  Baz:  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="foo"></ng-container>
</div>
```